# GoogleApiClient onConnected event is not triggered from from stand alone module

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-api-client, android-googleapiclient

I'm new to `JAVA` and `ANDROID` and tried to build an app to have the location as per [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html), so I wrote the below `helper` code:

```
package oryx.tecna.locateme;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

public class UtilLocation
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    protected static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    protected static Location mLastLocation;

    public UtilLocation(Context context) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Oryx.getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Oryx.getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Oryx.getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation == null)
            Toast.makeText(Oryx.getContext(), R.string.no_location_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(Oryx.getContext(), "Location found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(Oryx.getContext(), "Connection suspended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(Oryx.getContext(), "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I created the below to to get the `context`:

```
package oryx.tecna.locateme;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

public class Oryx extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Then I tried to call the above `helper` using the below code:

```
location = (new UtilLocation(context)).mLastLocation;
```

but the app had been crashed :(

What is the mistake I did  and how to get it fixed? thanks

**UPDATE**
I found one error, so i replaced the:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Oryx.getContext())
```

by:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
```

The app now is not crashing, but not returning the location, i.e. the `mLastLocation` is read as `nullذ

**Update 2**

Apparantly,

```
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
```

is not executed as none of the Toast appears, neither the one telling there is GPS, nor the one telling there is no GPS

Comment: Have you added permissions to the manifest?

Comment: yes @MichaelStoddart, apparently the `public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)` is not executed as I none of the `Toast` appears, neither the one telling there is GPS, nor the one telling there is no GPS

Comment: "The app now is not crashing, but not returning the location, i.e. the mLastLocation is read as null". That means you haven't yet received any coordinate. As soon as you receive one coordinate, after that `getLastLocation()` will return non-null value.

Comment: @azizbekian I understand that, , apparently the public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) is not executed as I none of the Toast appears, neither the one telling there is GPS, nor the one telling there is no GPS